# spring boot 1.5.x /hystrix.stream actuator not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-boot-actuator

I have the same issue as below.  A very simple Hystrix spring boot application failing to load actuator /hystrix.stream.

Application uses Spring boot starter parent 1.5.x and hystrix 1.5.x libs. It worked well with Spring boot 1.3.x. Other actuators are good.

There's seems to be a known problem with 1.4.x and 1.5.x, however **I'm looking for some workaround**. **Please don't suggest solutions for Spring boot 2.0.x.**

From the github issue:

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1566

We are using the Spring boot starter parent 1.5.2.RELEASE and hystrix 1.5.6 dependencies.
Fortunately it works once in hundred tries. We are really puzzled, why it works once and then never. All the services are running on the local machine.

The log details are as below:

`Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:6001/hystrix.stream
2017-05-05 12:29:16.951 INFO 4876 --- [nio-6001-exec-5] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet :
Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:6001/hystrix.stream
2017-05-05 12:31:36.163 INFO 4876 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration`

If we try to curl the end point instead of getting back a snapshot of data, we get

Previous versions of Spring-boot 1.3.x did not have an issue. At first sight, this seems to be an incompatibility with Spring-boot or one of it's dependencies since our team had not had issues until a recent upgrade with Hystrix.

Noteworthy comment is that all other parts of Hystrix are working just fine. RequestLog, and at least Circuit Breaking are working as designed. For some reason the Hystrix Streaming Servlet is no longer functional for us.

The symptoms we receive for this issue are as follows:

- Unable to connect to Command Stream (per description of ticket)
- Access log receives 503 http status entry for hystrix.stream end point

Comment: Can you please post the code in question.

Comment: I created a new service for this and it seems to be working with basic configuration. I'll have to figure out what is going on with my live service, I'm sure it might be a conflict with some libs.